# Firebase Analytics test

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to test Firebase analytics in a test page. Below is the code.

However, I see no traffic on the analytics plots.
No errors in the page logs. How should I continue to test my firebase is setup right? I just used it out of the box.

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>


  <script>
    // copied from the Firebase config page
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "hidden",
        authDomain: "hidden",
        databaseURL: "https://hidden.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "hidden",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "hidden",
        appId: "hidden",
        measurementId: "hidden"
      };

    // Initialize Firebase
    var fapp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();


    var button_push = function(){
        var analytics = firebase.analytics(fapp);
        var result = analytics.logEvent('INIT TEST', { name: 'TEST'});
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="button_push()">
    TEST
</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the SDK isn't working the way you expect, please contact Firebase support directly for troubleshooting assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I did. I do not understand why a minimal example fails. I used Google Analytics before but now it's Firebase. I bet I have some setup wrong and not seeing it.